# Passing an array of dictionary from Firebase to local arrays

Tags: firebase, swift3

I am trying to get an array of dictionaries from Firebase and pass to local equalize but get miscellanous error.

I have below struct example:

```
struct Places {
var type = ""
var country = ""
var name = ""

init(type: String, country: String, name: String, image: String) {
    self.type = type
    self.country = country
    self.name = name
}
```

And local array of Places type dictionary

```
    var allPlaces:[Places] = []
```

And here is my code snippet on ViewController

```
                if let firebasePlaces = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

                var localPlace:Places!

                for firebasePlace in firebasePlaces{

                    localPlace?.name = firebasePlace.value["name"] as! String
                    localPlace?.country = firebasePlace.value["country"] as! String
                    localPlace?.type = firebasePlace.value["type"] as! String
                    localPlace?.image = firebasePlace.value["image"] as! String


                    self.allPlaces.append(localPlace)

                }
        }
```

I have got "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on self.allPlaces.append(localPlace) line. What am I missing on above example, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed above code by making little changes.

The Places struct should be like below

```
struct Places {
var type:String!
var country:String!
var name:String!
var image:String!

init(type: String, country: String, name: String, image: String) {
    self.type = type
    self.country = country
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {

    let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! [String:AnyObject]

    type = snapshotValue["type"] as! String
    country = snapshotValue["country"] as! String
    name = snapshotValue["name"] as! String
    image = snapshotValue["image"] as! String
}
```

And code snippet on ViewController

```
                var plc: [Places] = []
                for eachPlace in (snapshot.children){
                let place = Places(snapshot: eachPlace as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                plc.append(place)
                }

                self.allPlaces = plc
```